# flipboard style square boxes with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Yesterday I have seen very cool animation on flipboard iPad application. Not the big animation which turns the page to the left or right but small boxes on the home screen gives an effect of manual scoreboards.

Like here; http://s5.thisnext.com/media/largest_dimension/014A3C75.jpg

Is there any Javascript library that feels like this animation? I looked at jQuery UI API but I couldn't find something even close to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/learn-how-to-create-a-retro-animated-flip-down-clock/